# Find all paths between specially paired nodes in a DAG in linear time

Tags: time-complexity, directed-acyclic-graph, 2sat

If I have a DAG with `2n` nodes partitioned into `n` pairs of nodes with `e` edges, is there a linear-time (`O(n + e)`) way to find the subset of all pairs for which there exists a path from one to the other?

So for instance, in the DAG (letting `\` and `/` be downward-pointing edges):

```
   A_1     C_2
  /   \   /   \
A_2    B_1     D_1
  \       \   /
   B_2     C_1
     \
      D_2
```

I want to return the set `{A_2, C_1}` since there exists a path from `A_1` to `A_2` and from `C_2` to `C_1`, but there's no (directed) path between `B_1` and `B_2` or between `D_1` and `D_2`.

---

Does it help to add the constraint that the graph be symmetric under reversing all the edges and swapping each node with its partner?

Comment: Context: I want to quickly identify all forced literals in a large 2-sat problem. I've already replaced each of the SCC's with a single representative which is why the graph is acyclic.